# Does it cost extra to support more memory in bios?

Tags: windows-7, memory, bios

Recently came across couple of low end machines with windows 7. They have 3 GB ram  installed, however the bios of these machines does not support more than 4GB. I can understand installed memory being low to keep the costs down, but don't understand why bios does not support reasonable extra memory like 8 or 16 GB. This prohibits machine upgraded in future.

Does it cost extra to add support for additional memory in bios? If we can get larger memory chips of same type of memory, why does bios not see it? In other words, why do manufactures limit maximum memory in bios and not keep it to maximum supported by cpu?

Comment: Your question is based on a faulty (i.e. incorrect) premise.  What you think is a "limitation" of the BIOS is actually a limitation of the hardware (e.g. the memory controller and/or motherboard).  Hardware to support more than 4GB of RAM does cost more (i.e. more address bits & signal lines).  The BIOS "limitation" is merely the user interface that you observe.  If you look at the motherboard schematics (if they were obtainable) then you could see the actual HW limitation.

Comment: So in other words, it costs more to support more memory. I think this is what question asked.

Answer (score 0):

My guess(without knowing the motherboard) would be that the RAM slots only support older versions of RAM(i.e DD2) and the RAM slots they have are limited. Due to the cost of manufacturing extra RAM slots(not to mention the area they take up) and the age of the motherboard, this is probably why you find low total supported RAM on motherboards in low-end computers.

Comment: Same memory slot can accept sizes in multiple like 1GB chip, 2GB chip and so on. Why does it limit it if I cross the limit

Comment: Yes, but if you are dealing with older RAM sticks(i.e DD2) oftentimes the maximum amount of memory per stick that you can buy is 2GB. Therefore, if you can only buy 2GB sticks and you have two RAM slots, the maximum supported memory s 4GB.

Answer (score 0):

The architecture of some older computers simply can not handle more than 3.5GB of RAM.  This is something that can not be fixed on those machines.  I think Linux has some work around called PAE but I do not know much about that.  Bottomline it is has to do with the capabilities of the machine hardware and the OS running on that hardware.

Comment: Say windows 7, 64 bit. It can certainly handle 8 gb or more.Why does bios not support it? My original question also mentions win 7

Comment: is it a 32bit version of win7?